# How to set a theme as default in terminal

Tags: mac, macos, themes, terminal

While I'm sure I need to use defaults write com.apple.Terminal to do this, I'm not sure how to use a terminal theme file like IR_Black.terminal and set it to the default theme for a user.

Basically, I'd like to be able to do something like defaults write com.apple.Terminal Default Window Setting IR_Black.terminal

anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just configure your window the way you want it and then choose the *Shell->Use Settings as Default* command. There's no need to do anything from the command line.

From your comment, I understand that you want to be able to set the preferences for Terminal from a script as part of configuring a machine automatically. The easiest way to do that is probably to configure Terminal the way you want, and then make a copy of

```
/Users/*yourname*/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

If you then copy that file to the target machine's

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

it'll become the default Terminal preferences for every user on that machine. Or, you can copy it to:

```
/Users/*username*/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

to set the Terminal preferences just for user *username*.

You probably already know at least some of this. I know this answer skirts the question of how to do the equivalent thing with the `defaults` command, but if you do:

```
% defaults read com.apple.Terminal
```

you'll see that the value for the "Window Settings" key is a fairly complex dictionary that's going to be difficult to manipulate with `defaults`. I think it'll be much safer to let Terminal write the settings, and for you to simply copy the entire settings file.

Comment: Caleb - I'm deploying environments to multiple users. I can't rely on them to do this on their own (don't get me started on why)

Comment: @CoryCollier: Edited my answer to help (I hope) with your situation. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I understand I am late to this question but I just solved a similar issue myself.  Here was what I did:

1. Export the style from the plist by running:

   ```
   $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist -c 'print ":Window Settings:SETTINGNAME"' > SETTINGNAME.plist
   ```
2. Copy the plist to another machine
3. On the other machine, run:

   ```
   $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist -c 'add ":Window Settings:SETTINGNAME" dict'
   $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist -c 'merge SETTINGNAME.plist ":Window Settings:SETTINGNAME"'
   ```

Then you can set the default color scheme with `defaults`.